# Failed to execute child process "/bin/sh" (input/output error)

Tags: suspend, gui, bios, 22.10

I am using RedmiBook with ryzen 5 4500u, Ubuntu 22.10 (22.04 have same problem)
Every time after waking up from suspend and working correctly for few seconds, it starting to throw an error from title, close all windows ans doesn't open new ones, also all icons become default ones (icons of apps, even the cursor, which looks like an GUI error.
Also on startup it shows: `usci_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)`
All answers from this topics didn't work for me. Also safe mode (after visiting grub menu) works fine, without any errors.
I have tried: Configuring grub file, reinstalling ubuntu, testing ssd for errors (everything fine), updating.
Also as I found out there is no drivers for this laptop.
It seems like there is a problem in BIOS settings, which are not fully unlocked on this laptop
Since I can't screenshot the error, I will take a photo by my phone, don't be mad))

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this as I have the exact same issue. I've heard that it may be because the hard drive partition is possibly corrupted.